# Copying Thousands of Files on the same HD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, rsync

I found myself in a situation I am copying an entire filesystem across two different HD partitions (different sizes and filesystem types). The problem so far is taht both `cp` and `rsync` will read a single file at the source, and write it on the destination - doing that for every small file. Therefore, I have only some small OS buffering and the HD cache itself to prevent the HD head to move back and forth for each small file - but it feels it is quite close to that.

The machine is got plenty of RAM. What could I do to say, read several megabytes (or even GB) worth of data on the same partition before comiting that on the other partition?

If it matters I am copying from BTRFS to EXt4 - data includes several git trees, source files and such (few large video and audio files).

Comment: Copy is over with rsync by now :-)  but still, a clever way to do this would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try playing with `cpio` or `tar` piping, for example using `cpio`'s `--io-size`

That said, I don't believe you would get better performance than you can achieve leaving `cp` or `rsync` do their jobs. It's actually the job of the filesystem and the underlying OS to deal with hdd driver behaviour and help it decide whether to seek or not.

You might get a better insight on this with this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-an-sane-safe-and-efficient-way). Particularly:

> EDIT: Ah, "native Linux" may be improving performance by interleaving
>   reads and writes with asynchronous I/O. Letting commands pile up can
>   help the disk driver decide when is best to seek. You might try Boost
>   Asio or pthreads for comparison. As for "can't beat POSIX file
>   descriptors"… well that's true if you're doing anything with the data,
>   not just blindly copying.